# Avoid CAS login page, use my own login page

Tags: single-sign-on, cas

I am new to CAS and single signon. Please correct me if my understanding is incorrect, below if what I understand about CAS.

1. I have 2 web applications
2. I setup CAS, and when I access URL of WebApp1, it shows me the CAS login page
3. I fill correct username/password
4. It takes me in WebApp1
5. From there I access WebApp2, and it works fine

What I need is as follows:

1. When I access WebApp1, I must see WebApp1 login page, not that of CAS
2. Let CAS generate some token for the session
3. Use this token to authenticate WebApp2 (which the way its working now - step 5 above)

Can someone suggest me how to achieve this?

I am using Java 1.6, CAS 3.4.11, Tomcat 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a summary recently on [how CAS works](http://hons82.blogspot.com/2012/01/single-sign-on-with-cas.html).

The principles are written there. Basically it is like this

1. Access The WebApp1
2. Show the CAS login page and authenticate
3. redirect to WebApp1
   Now subsequently you do the following
4. Access WebApp2
5. the access request is redirected to CAS which without showing a login page authenticates the user

Always under the assumption that both WebApps are configured to use CAS as a login provider and CAS is setup to support both WebApps.

Now in the CAS way what you want to achieve is done like this:
*exchange the standard CAS login page with your login page and your done*

Comment: can you elaborate a little bit? How does one setup CAS in order to us both webapps login page as "valid" cas login pages?

Comment: You're never using both login pages. The login is moved on the CAS server and both webapps just redirect to it

Comment: i'm going through a few workarounds... check this out: https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CAS/Using+CAS+without+the+Login+Screen

Comment: Okay, I came over that when I implemented our solution, but at the End till now we don't need it to work like that, so I can't tell you if this solution works. However try it out, the comments at the end are quite optimistic :-D